# What differences are between web service and ssh?

Tags: web-services, ssh

I was wondering what differences between [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) and ssh are?

Are they both remote control of computers/servers?

Does ssh belong to web service?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH is a communications protocol for remote login/control of a machine. A web service is some method of accessing data via a web server.

There's no comparison between the two. One's a road (ssh), and one's a retail store (web service).

The underlying protocols of SSH (SSL - secure sockets layer) can be used to secure communications with a webservice, but that's about the only thing in common between the two.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Regarding a web service, what do "method" and "retail store" mean?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/method for 'retail store', it's just a metaphor - a place that has stuff you want, and a well defined means of accessing/getting that stuff.

Comment: Thanks! Why ssh is not a method?

Comment: It is a method, but it's a method of logging into a remote computer and issuing commands. A webservice could vaguely also be seen as a "login" to a remote computer with "commands" that you've issued, but at a much higher lever than ssh. ssh is just how you do a secure remote command line interface.